# Improve performance for a SQL query that returns the same result for 24 hours

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, postgresql, caching, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails app, I only do 10 unique SQL queries. However, each takes a long time (1 - 5 seconds). The result of each query only changes every 24 hours.

What solutions are available to make this more performant?

I'm using Postgres and Ruby on Rails.

Should I be caching query results somewhere? Should I be using "stored procedures" (don't know what they are yet)? Is there something else I should be researching?

Comment: Are these 10 queries exactly the same every time you run them? If so, why don't you create 10 tables with the results (and update them every 24h) and query these tables instead of doing your "10 complex queries"? Or you can use Materialized views, but this needs to be in 9.3 or above...

Comment: The 10 queries are identical every time. The queries are not complex, but they are selecting a ton of data. I guess populating their own tables nightly with the finished result could work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use `Rails.cache` like so:

```
def self.some_long_query_that_changes_every_day
  Rails.cache.fetch ['some_cache_key'], expires_in: 12.hours do
    self.where(field: value)
  end
end
```

`fetch` will either read from the unexpired cache or make the db query and store it in the cache with that key.

The only tricky part is the `expires_in` part. Depending on when exactly your data changes, you might want to compute the `expires_in` depending on what time it gets stored.

```
expire_in = Time.now.utc.end_of_day - Time.now.utc
Rails.cache.fetch ['some_cache_key'], expires_in: expire_in....
```

Or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using at least version 9.3 then maybe [Materialized views](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Materialized_Views)? That way you have the stored results in the table-like view and you can refresh the results every 24h with the command: REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW.

If your query returns a lot of rows you could consider some other options (caching the results within the program etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Generate a static HTML or XML document from the query and serve that.

One a day, generate a new static document.

This has the lowest possible overhead.